# Unable to find schema for element

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I'm trying to import an external wsdl and generate an apex class, but I'm getting the error:

```
Unable to find schema for element; {http://webservices.tmaresources.com/personify/}DEMO_UpdateCustomerDemographicsResponse
```

I can't paste the whole file because it exceeds the allotted character limit, but here is the wsdl definitions where I think the issue is occurring:

```
    <wsdl:definitions xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://webservices.tmaresources.com/personify/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://webservices.tmaresources.com/personify/">
    <wsdl:types>...</wsdl:types>
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`http://webservices.tmaresources.com/personify/` does not exist. Probably you have an old WSDL definition.

You could try deleting that `targetNamespace="http://webservices.tmaresources.com/personify/"` bit. Roughly speaking targetNamespace allows the document to refer to itself later on (Google for proper explanations, I'm by no means a SOAP guru). So no promises - some other things in the WSDL might fail too (and if that's the endpoint which you are supposed to be calling - the code wouldn't work anyway, right?)

It seems the company is in process of rebranding (http://www.personifycorp.com/) and that quite a lot on their website doesn't work (http://www.personifycorp.com/products-services/enterprise gives me 404 even though I've clicked that link on their own page).

I don't think it's a programming-related question as such. Contact them directly and ask to sort their $#*^ out. Maybe they'll provide you with correct version of the WSDL... and maybe the webservice is completely down and there's nothing you can do.